# AdMob Ios Error: Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, admob

i would add ADMOB to my xcode project, but when a test it on iphone and simulator i receive this error :

> AdMob Ios Error: Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show.

my code Banner.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"

@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;

@interface BannerExampleViewController : UIViewController
    <GADBannerViewDelegate> {
  GADBannerView *adBanner_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GADBannerView *adBanner;

- (GADRequest *)createRequest;

@end
```

Banner.m

```
#import "BannerExampleViewController.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"
#import "SampleConstants.h"

@implementation BannerExampleViewController

@synthesize adBanner = adBanner_;

#pragma mark init/dealloc

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view,
// typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
  CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                               self.view.frame.size.height -
                               CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

  // Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
  self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                  origin:origin]
                    autorelease];

  // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
  // before compiling.
  self.adBanner.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;
  self.adBanner.delegate = self;
  [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
  [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
  self.adBanner.center =
      CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
  [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  adBanner_.delegate = nil;
  [adBanner_ release];
  [super dealloc];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma mark GADRequest generation

// Here we're creating a simple GADRequest and whitelisting the application
// for test ads. You should request test ads during development to avoid
// generating invalid impressions and clicks.
- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
  GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

  // Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for the simulator as
  // well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
  request.testDevices =
      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"6a47e320f03fe2ab9854afe2e5708321", nil];
  return request;
}

#pragma mark GADBannerViewDelegate impl

// We've received an ad successfully.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}

@end
```

Comment: everything looks good make sure that your "kSampleAdUnitID" key for AdMob is perfect.

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper yes.. i'm sure

Comment: same error: Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show.

Comment: try replacing this line i have doubt on that 

request.testDevices =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     nil]; remove key "6a47e320f03fe2ab9854afe2e5708321"

Comment: works! thanks for your time .. saved me .. does it works in production mode?

Comment: i think so....never tried so not sure but you can try it by your self and share the result :)

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper  with my id does not work ! why ?

Comment: might be issue while you created add on AdMob try to create new add with your account.

Answer (score 6):

One more thing to point out - if your banner space width/height is set ot 0, you'll receive exactly the same error. I'm currently trying to make a workaround about this because I want to animate ad view on screen only if it successfully load ad.

Comment: Got it, Admob doesn't like we use hidden on the banner view. But it likes when we remove and add from the and to the superview. The animation less elegant. but no errors!

Comment: Hi have you Solved this.. height issues

Comment: Do not set the view `isHidden` property. Do not set the view height to 0. If you want to hide the view if an ad could not be loaded, use the adView(_: didFailToReveiveAdWithError) method and **set the view height to 1** instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server have not update yet.
You should wait for 15 minutes and try again, it will work correctly.

**PS:** Remember replace kSampleAdUnitID with your App ID in Admob

This code work correctly when I am testing with my ID

Comment: How did you know that we should wait for 15 minutes?

Comment: Server is not response immediately, this is why you should wait. If you add your app and make your game run immediately, it will not work because it is not in the system.

Comment: Ahh you mean, wait for 15 minutes after you have added? How about the interval between ads?

Comment: I mean wait 15 mins after you add your app to server Admob. In your game, you just call and it will appear after 2 second ^.^

Comment: Ohhhh.. The app is already added to server Admob. My issue is that sometimes there is no ad, sometimes there is ad...