# google admob ios: Request Error: No ad to show

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I found a related thread [AdMob Ios Error: Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295552/admob-ios-error-failed-to-receive-ad-with-error-request-error-no-ad-to-show) but it does not solve my problem.

I am trying to create an Interstitial ad using the latest example project from google code:  https://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/InterstitialExample_iOS_3.0.zip.

I have changed `kSampleAdUnitID` to that of my ad id.

Yesterday, when I clicked on `Load Interstitial`, I got `Request Error: No ad to show`. I had to click 4-5 times for it to work.

Today, I am using the same code unchanged but no matter how many times I click on `Load Interstitial`, I get the error mentioned above.

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

My implementation as follows - I hope it helps:

```
@interface ViewController () <GADInterstitialDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) GADInterstitial *interstitial;   
@end   


@implementation ViewController

#define MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID @"...."

- (void)preLoadInterstitial {
    //Call this method as soon as you can - loadRequest will run in the background and your interstitial will be ready when you need to show it
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
 }

- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    //An interstitial object can only be used once - so it's useful to automatically load a new one when the current one is dismissed
    [self preLoadInterstitial];
}

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    //If an error occurs and the interstitial is not received you might want to retry automatically after a certain interval
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(preLoadInterstitial) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) showInterstitial
{
    //Call this method when you want to show the interstitial - the method should double check that the interstitial has not been used before trying to present it
    if (!self.interstitial.hasBeenUsed) [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for `if (!self.interstitial.hasBeenUsed)`