# Integration of adMob: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I have switched over from iAd to adMob and am having a hard time integrating the banner ads.

When I run the code, I get the `fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

Here is my code:

```
      import GoogleMobileAds


  class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView =  view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)


    print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
    var banner: GADBannerView!
   banner.delegate = self
   banner.adUnitID = " ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx" //crashing on this line
    banner.loadRequest(GADRequest())

   }
}
```

I feel like I've followed this properly from the AdMob website, but Im having a hard time figuring out where this error is coming from. Is/has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You haven't initialized your `banner` anywhere, so you should either create an `@IBOutlet` for it if you want to create it in the interface builder, or initialize it programmatically. This is most likely why your app crashes.

   ```
   var banner: GADBannerView!
   banner = GADBannerView(frame: self.view.frame) // Initialized, with fullscreen frame
   ```
2. The `adUnitID` shouldn't start with a space.

Comment: Okay thank you. How would I initialize it programmatically?

Comment: @KeepItSimple Updated answer

Comment: Thank you, no crash (: I'm now getting a `request error, no ad to show. ` Is this a serious issue?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22267522/5389870). The error might have to do with your banner not having a frame, so you should create a frame for your banner at initialization. See updated answer again.

Comment: Thanks so much. Im not getting any test ads but I don't have the error. I think it'll be fine when I launch it.